# Set React ref after component updates

Tags: reactjs

I need to focus the user on a `<Message />` component after they answer a question or change their answer. This message does not display on the initial render when the answer has not yet been answered.

When I try to `focus()` on the `<Message />` component using a ref, I get the error message:

`Cannot read property 'focus' of null`

I think because this message renders only after the component updates. How can I set this ref after the component updates?

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.answer !== this.props.answer) {
      console.log(this.message); // logs null
      this.message.focus(); // Cannot read property 'focus' of null
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { // if the user has answer the question, show a message
          this.props.answer !== null ?
            <Message
              ref={(message) => { this.message = message; }}
            /> 
            : null
        }
      </div> 
    );
  }
}
```

***Edit***

I just realized that because this Message component comes from semantic-ui, it might be a stateless functional component which would mean it cannot have a ref.

Comment: Why not just check to see if the ref is null before trying to focus it?

Comment: @DaveNewton How will that help me focus on the Message component?

Comment: Can you show the code for your `Message` component?

Comment: @chris we are using semantic-ui https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/message

Comment: The ref will correctly be null whenever `this.props.answer` is null (since you're deciding whether or not to render a message based on `this.props.answer`). So, you won't be able to avoid the null check suggested by @Dave Newton.

Comment: @chris the purpose of the focus is for accessibility. If a user is blind and using a screen reader, we want to focus them on the message so the screen reader will read it.

Comment: @plmok61, gotcha. I haven't used Semantic before but doesn't `Message` transpile into a `div`?

Comment: @plmok61 ...  the point is to avoid the null reference if it hasn't been rendered.

Comment: @plmok61 If the component is stateless, you can create your own stateful wrapper component that you can set the ref on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the ref on a wrapper element instead of on the actual component:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.answer !== this.props.answer) {
      console.log(this.message); // logs null
      this.message.focus(); // Cannot read property 'focus' of null
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { // if the user has answer the question, show a message
          this.props.answer !== null &&
            <div ref={ message => this.message = message }>
              <Message/> 
            </div>
        }
      </div> 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you trigger `focus` on a div??

Comment: @Chris You can add a `tabindex` to the div to get `.focus()` working: https://jsfiddle.net/5onuxyqb/1/. My guess is that OP actually needs to focus on something inside the div though.